# .NET JSON Serialization with extra properties

Tags: .net, json, rest, serialization, json.net

I have a REST API that is serving applications in 'the wild' and working fine.  The API and the consumer work off the same data model so the objects the API returns in JSON format parse directly to the data objects in the consumer.  This all works great.  I'm using Flurl to receive the data which deserializes using Newtonsoft.JSON I'm pretty sure.

Now there are a few things that I would like to add to the data model (and back end data entries in the DB) to make the API more capable.  These are not properties that the consumer should care about, but if I add them to the data model objects the API will pass them through and return them.  Will the .NET consumer complain about this or ignore them?

So for instance say I have this returned presently as a user:

```
{
  Username: "something",
  Email: "someone@somewhere.com"
}
```

However if I make the changes to the API it will return something like this:

```
{
  Username: "something",
  Email: "someone@somewhere.com",
  Search: "SOME SEARCH FIELD DATA"
}
```

Will the consumer start throwing de-serialization errors or just ignore the extra value?  I tried to Google but all I found was stuff about how to deserialize JSON data yourself...

Since it's out publicly I would have to do it a different way if this would throw an error, but it would be really nice not to have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extra field will just be ignored. If you try to deserialize JSON into an object class, and the class is missing some fields that exist in the JSON, the missing fields will just not get deserialized.

Something that WILL break the consumer side is if you change the data type in your JSON.

For example, changing `Username: "something"` to `Username: 100` will break the consumer, because you just changed data type from a `string` to `int`.